# 2000 Mazda protege the efi fuse blows out

Tags: electrical, mazda, fuse, fuel-injection, protege

Fuse blows out as soon as the key is in the on position. I have unplugged all the fuel injectors and the fuel pump at the tank and still blows the fuse. I'm not sure if I have the correct relays for the main and the fuel pump but it's been running for 2 weeks with them.and now all of a sudden the fuse blows for efi....

No codes.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: In an ideal world, you would say which engine you have, and you would post a clear wiring diagram that includes the efi fuse, or a non-paywalled link to it. You can get a short term **single vehicle auto repair data subscription**, including wiring diagrams. Search that phrase to find one.

Comment: I think the obvious thing here is you are going to have to trace the wire which goes between the fuse and the distant end (not the battery end) to see where it is shorting. If it's not the injectors and it's not the fuel pump, it has to be a dead short somewhere.

Comment: Thank you for the replies, actually what is actually grounded is the wire coming off the main relay. The efi fuse supplies power to the main relay. The wire that the main relay is supplying power to is shorted. I can't find a wiring diagram that shows me what that is. For free anyways. 1.6l engine and 5 speed manual transmission. I had the same problem about 3 weeks ago and it turned out to be the speed sensor.. I have it unplugged still. It was shutting the engine down at 25mph back then.